# python Non-block read file

Tags: python, python-2.7, nonblocking

I want to read a file with non-block mode.
So i did like below

```
import fcntl
import os

fd = open("./filename", "r")
flag = fcntl.fcntl(fd.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFD)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFD, flag | os.O_NONBLOCK)
flag = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFD)
if flag & os.O_NONBLOCK:
    print "O_NONBLOCK!!"
```

But the value `flag` still represents 0.
Why..? i think i should be changed according to `os.O_NONBLOCK`

And of course, if i call fd.read(), it is blocked at read().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`O_NONBLOCK` is a status flag, not a descriptor flag. Therefore use `F_SETFL` to [set File status flags](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html), not `F_SETFD`, which is for [setting File descriptor flags](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html).

Also, be sure to pass an integer file descriptor as the first argument to `fcntl.fcntl`, not the Python file object. Thus use

```
f = open("/tmp/out", "r")
fd = f.fileno()
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, flag | os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

rather than

```
fd = open("/tmp/out", "r")
...
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFD, flag | os.O_NONBLOCK)
flag = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFD)
```

---

```
import fcntl
import os

with open("/tmp/out", "r") as f:
    fd = f.fileno()
    flag = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, flag | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    flag = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    if flag & os.O_NONBLOCK:
        print "O_NONBLOCK!!"
```

prints

```
O_NONBLOCK!!
```