# Why isn't my file corrupted while writing to it from multiple processes in Python?

Tags: python, linux, file, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

It seems obvious that writing from multiple process to the same file may cause corrupted data if the `write()` calls are not somehow synchronized. See this other question: [Python multiprocessing safely writing to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446445/python-multiprocessing-safely-writing-to-a-file).

However, while trying to reproduce this possible bug for testing purposes, **I was not able** to cause the file messages to be mixed up. I wanted to do this to effectively compare with and without the lock security.

Without doing anything, file seems somehow protected.

```
import multiprocessing
import random

NUM_WORKERS = 10
LINE_SIZE = 10000
NUM_LINES = 10000

def writer(i):
    line = ("%d " % i) * LINE_SIZE + "\n"
    with open("file.txt", "a") as file:
        for _ in range(NUM_LINES):
            file.write(line)

def check(file):
    for _ in range(NUM_LINES * NUM_WORKERS):
        values = next(file).strip().split()
        assert len(values) == LINE_SIZE
        assert len(set(values)) == 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []

    for i in range(NUM_WORKERS):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=writer, args=(i, ))
        processes.append(process)

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
        check(file)
```

I'm using Linux and I also know that file-writing may be atomic depending on the buffer size: [Is file append atomic in UNIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154446/is-file-append-atomic-in-unix).

I tried to increase the size of the messages, but it doesn't produce corrupted data.

Do you know of any code sample I could use that produce corrupted files using multiprocessing on Linux?

Comment: I managed to corrupt the file when i write char-by-char, not by lines: `for c in line: file.write(c)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely In such case this is expected, I guess, as there is multiple `write` operations explicitly. I thought one call to `file.write()` wasn't even supposed to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU, the locking is done by the kernel. The reason you see the effects of locking even though you didn't ask for it is that the `O_NONBLOCK` file status flag is unset by default (when opening the file, I guess).

Consult the section of the manual on *file status flags*, in particular, see [operating modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Operating-Modes.html#Operating-Modes) and `man 2 fcntl`.

I patched your example thusly to see the effects of `O_NONBLOCK` (and indeed, the assertion does fail now):

```
--- 1.py.orig   2019-07-05 14:49:13.276289018 +0300
+++ 1.py        2019-07-05 14:51:11.674727731 +0300
@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
 import multiprocessing
 import random
+import os
+import fcntl

 NUM_WORKERS = 10
 LINE_SIZE = 10000
@@ -8,6 +10,8 @@
 def writer(i):
     line = ("%d " % i) * LINE_SIZE + "\n"
     with open("file.txt", "a") as file:
+        flag = fcntl.fcntl(file.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFD)
+        fcntl.fcntl(file.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, flag | os.O_NONBLOCK)
         for _ in range(NUM_LINES):
             file.write(line)
```

Credit: see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30172682/2104472) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42442886/2104472) (and/or `man 3p write`).